# c++: how is this a semantic error

Tags: c++, clang

this kind of error bewilders me...

code:

```
class TankSystem
{
  //  
  // instance variables
  //  
  private:
    TankController _tlTank;
    TankController _trTank;
    TankController _blTank;
    TankController _brTank;

    Pump _leftPump;
    Pump _rightPump;

  //  
  // constructor methods
  //  
  public:
    TankSystem( TankSystemInfo info, PumpInfo left, PumpInfo right ) 
    {   
      _tlTank = TankController( info.tanks[0] );  
      _trTank = TankController( info.tanks[1] );
      _blTank = TankController( info.tanks[2] );  
      _brTank = TankController( info.tanks[3] );
      _leftPump = Pump( left );
      _rightPump = Pump( right );
    }
```

here i have a system with 6 data members: 4 tank objects and 2 pump objects.

and I get this error...

> include/TankSystem.hpp:32:5: error: constructor for 'TankSystem' must
>   explicitly initialize the member '_tlTank' which does not have
>         a default constructor
>       TankSystem( TankSystemInfo info, PumpInfo left, PumpInfo right ) 
>       ^ include/TankSystem.hpp:20:20: note: member is declared here
>       TankController _tlTank;
>                      ^ include/TankController.hpp:26:7: note: 'TankController' declared here class TankController

Once per instance variable. So I get 6 errors in total here...
hardware: 2011 11' MacBook Air

os: OSX 10.9.3

compiler: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

Comment: Because if your class has members of other classes they will get initialized before the constructor. Search for 'Initialization List' for more informations.

Comment: The *syntax* is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `TankSystem` object is constructed, all fields are initialized before the constructor body is executed. Because there's no default constructor for `TankController` (and you're not calling any other constructor explicitly) compiler can't instantiate these fields.

So, instead of

```
TankSystem( TankSystemInfo info, PumpInfo left, PumpInfo right ) 
{   
  _tlTank = TankController( info.tanks[0] );  
  _trTank = TankController( info.tanks[1] );
  _blTank = TankController( info.tanks[2] );  
  _brTank = TankController( info.tanks[3] );
  _leftPump = Pump( left );
  _rightPump = Pump( right );
}
```

do

```
TankSystem( TankSystemInfo info, PumpInfo left, PumpInfo right ) :
   _tlTank(info.tanks[0]), _trTank(info.tanks[1]), _blTank(info.tanks[2]),
   _brTank(info.tanks[3]), _leftPump(left), _rightPump(right)
{   
}
```

Even if you had default constructor, you should go with b) solution because in the case a) objects would first be initialized by the default constructor, then the `TankController(info.tanks[0])` constructor would be executed creating a temp object, and then `operator=` would be called to copy the values from the temp object into the existing object.

Answer (score 2):

First, the fix:

```
TankSystem( TankSystemInfo info, PumpInfo left, PumpInfo right ) 
: _tlTank( info.tanks[0] ),
  _trTank( info.tanks[1] ),
  _blTank( info.tanks[2] ),
  _brTank( info.tanks[3] ),
  _leftPump( left ),
  _rightPump( right )
{
}
```

This should make your code compile.

As for the reason, C++ requires member variables to be initialized before entering the body of the constructor, which requires the use of an initialization list. Your code uses assignments, which would be fine if your `TankController` and `Pump` classes had default constructors: your code would call the default constructor before entering the body of `TankSystem::TankSystem`; then it would re-assign the values. However, both classes lack the default constructor, triggering the error.

Answer (score 1):

Because when code in your constructor starts fields should be already initialized, but it's impossible because there are no default constructor. Use initialization list instead.